# angularjs: How to make elements in a list flash up one by one

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have the following HTML/Angular code that list elements in a tabulated format

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="currElement in myCtrl.elementList track by $index" >
    <td ng-class-odd="'element-tilt-left'" ng-class-even="'element-tilt-right'">
      <a ui-sref="myState({elementId: currElement.elementId)" ng-bind="currElement.name">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I would like each element in `myCtrl.elementList` to show up for 5 seconds, then fade out for 2 seconds. While it is fading out, the next element should fade in. And in turn, it should stay visible for five seconds before fading out.

I would like it to go through the entire list in this way. And then circle back up to the first element -- thus continuing the cycle indefinitely.

How can I do all that?

Comment: This can be done using gsap. See http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/

Comment: It's a little unclear what exact effect you're looking for.. Did you want to only show a single row, and have each bit of content fade in and out of it, or do you want the full table visible throughout the animation and just "highlight" one at a time?